# SQL update from one Table A to table B based on match 2 ID based on aggregation of points

Tags: sql, vertica

trying to update the value to table(final) from table(first_stage), both of these tables have the same field name but different values, tables contents are:

```
(Min_Date) date, 
(Max_Date) date, 
(NoofDays) int, 
(IMSI) string, 
(Site) string, 
(Down_Link) int, 
(Up_Link) int, 
(Connection) int
```

based on IMSI and Site, if it exists on the table row then take the minimum date as Min_Date and Maximum date as Max_Date and get the

```
min(Min_Date),max(Max_Date)sum(NoofDays),sum(Down_Link),sum(up_Link),sum(connection)
```

and if the both of row id's are not matched(IMSI,Site) with table (Final) then insert the row into final table. I'm still newbee with sql

```
table first_stage:
MinDate    Max_Date  NoofDays  IMSI  Site   Down_link  Up_link  Connection
2019-03-22 2019-03-26   1       222  google    1        1         1
2019-03-26 2019-03-27   3       222  youtube   1        1         1
2019-03-02 2019-03-27   5       333  facebook  2        3         1
2019-03-02 2019-03-27   5       111  facebook  20       33        11



table final:
MinDate    Max_Date  NoofDays  IMSI  Site   Down_link  Up_link  Connection
2019-03-01 2019-03-27   1       222  google    2        2         1
2019-03-12 2019-03-25   1       222  youtube   2        2         2
2019-03-25 2019-03-27   4       333  facebook  3        6         1
```

it must matched with both IMSI and Site to make update statement, final table after update must be look like as the below:

```
table final:
MinDate    Max_Date  NoofDays  IMSI  Site   Down_link  Up_link  Connection
2019-03-01 2019-03-27   2       222  google    3        3         2
2019-03-12 2019-03-27   4       222  youtube   3        3         3
2019-03-02 2019-03-27   9       333  facebook  5        9         2
2019-03-02 2019-03-27   5       111  facebook  20       33        11
```

Comment: Add some sample data, preferably in the form of a t-sql script. Add the desired result, and you will get help in no time.

Comment: I haved added the samples , thank you for your support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never worked with vertica, but I think this might work:

```
MERGE 
INTO FINAL 
USING FIRST_STAGE
ON IMSI = FIRST_STAGE.IMSI and Site = FIRST_STAGE.Site
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
  Min_Date = least(FIRST_STAGE.Min_Date, Min_Date),
  Max_Date = greatest(FIRST_STAGE.Max_Date, Max_Date),
  NoofDays = FIRST_STAGE.NoofDays + NoofDays,
  Down_Link = FIRST_STAGE.Down_Link + Down_Link,
  up_Link = FIRST_STAGE.up_Link + up_Link,
  connection = FIRST_STAGE.connection + connection
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT ( Min_Date, 
  Max_Date, 
  NoofDays, 
  IMSI, 
  Site, 
  Down_Link, 
  Up_Link, 
  Connection )
VALUES ( FIRST_STAGE.Min_Date, 
  FIRST_STAGE.Max_Date, 
  FIRST_STAGE.NoofDays, 
  FIRST_STAGE.IMSI, 
  FIRST_STAGE.Site, 
  FIRST_STAGE.Down_Link, 
  FIRST_STAGE.Up_Link, 
  FIRST_STAGE.Connection )
```